# Events not firing html5 player

Tags: soundcloud

Has the html5 player / api been updated? The events

- SC.Widget.Events.PLAY,
- SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE,
- SC.Widget.Events.FINISH,

from the html5 player are not firing anymore. Can somebody confirm?

Comment: it looks like they have some issues. this is the code that worked before.
http://jsfiddle.net/5XnSq/

Comment: Not firing for me too, and I keep getting these errors:
`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost/example/ from frame with URL https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1234567. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.`
And:
`Unable to post message to http://w.soundcloud.com. Recipient has origin https://w.soundcloud.com.`
(if this helps in any kind of way)

Answer (score 0):

Recently a redirect from HTTP -> HTTPS has been introduced for all widgets which caused some problems with widget API.
I'm trying to fix it at the moment.

Comment: Any news on that? I have the same issue, the links work neither with SSL on or off.

Comment: Is the thing that "Gil Goldshlager" mentioned above (protocols not matching) related to this? Or was that fixed already?Things are mostly working for me with the HTML5 widget API, but now and again FINISH doesn't work (especially if it's a 1 second song) and now again calling `play()` on the widget fails.